# Nokogiri and random div name

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, wildcard

Using Nokogiri and Ruby.

I have a page to parse with div id's like:

div id="some-list-number^875"

Numbers after ...-number^ changes  random, and i just can't do

```
doc.css('#wikid-list-genres^875').each do |n|  
       puts n.text.to_s
end
```

But the base structure is always the same -number^..some digits...

So i need some kind of wildmask for those digits.

How can I deal with that using ruby and Nokogiri?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `^=` to match the beginning of an attribute, e.g. `div[id^=wikid-list-genres]`. (Source: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors))

However, I noticed that your id attribute has a `^` character in it, which is not allowed in ids, so "wikid-list-genres^875" is not a valid id and will likely cause you problems down the road. (Source: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-is-a-valid-value-for-id-attributes-in-html)) May I suggest changing it to "wikid-list-genres-875" or "wikid-list-genres_875"?